# How can I set one JQGrid Pager to 2 different Grids

Tags: jqgrid, uinavigationbar, toolbar, pager

I'm trying to use only one Pager, the same functions, for 2 Grids, but it's not working like I wish it would...

I set the element ID at the **pager** JqGrid property,  but it's not working properly...

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use one pager `div` per one jqGrid and not try to share only one pager. Sharing of pager are **not supported**.

If you can explain what problem you try to solve with the sharing of one pager I'll try to suggest another solution of your problem.